# Why Salesforce Ocapi customer deleted not working?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-commerce-cloud

I'm reaching out for some assistance with a problem I've encountered while setting up hooks in the Business Manager of my Salesforce Commerce Cloud instance.

I've activated the hooks in the BM and created a `hooks.json` file, which I've also referenced in my `package.json`.

My hooks.json looks like this:

```html
{
    "hooks": [{
        "name" : "app.template.afterFooter",
        "script" : "./cartridge/scripts/hooks/initGlobals.js"
    },
    {
        "name": "dw.ocapi.data.customer_list.customer.afterDELETE",
        "script": "./cartridge/scripts/hooks/customerHooks.js"
      }
    ]
}
```

Additionally, I've crafted my customerHooks.js file as follows:

```html
var HookManager = require("dw/system/HookMgr");
var LOGGER = require('dw/system/Logger').getLogger('logme');


exports.afterDELETE = function afterDELETE(customerListId) {
    var Status = require('dw/system/Status');
    LOGGER.debug('Test');
    return new Status(Status.OK);
};
```

However, despite this setup, I'm not seeing any logs in the Log Center related to this hook. Could anyone provide insights into what might be going wrong or what I might be missing?

Just to add a point, the hook :"app.template.afterFooter" is working fine and i have a log.

Thank you in advance for your time and help!

Best regards.